# Adding and removing checked of the second checkbox when the first is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code with two checkboxes, now when I turn on the first checkbox - the second is turned on, you need to do more so that when my checkboxes are active and I turn off the first box and turn off the second

```js
function onToggle() {
  if (document.querySelector('#viberOne').checked) {
    // if checked
    console.log('checked');
    document.getElementById("viberTwo").checked = true
  } else {
    // if unchecked
    console.log('unchecked');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="viberOne" onclick="onToggle()" type="checkbox" name="viberOne">
<input id="viberTwo" type="checkbox" name="viberTwo">
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: your question still isn't clear.  Do you want to have the second box auto checked when the first box is checked and cleared of the check when the first is unchecked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onToggle() {
  if (document.querySelector('#viberOne').checked) {
    // if checked
    console.log('checked');
    document.getElementById("viberTwo").checked = true
  } else {
    // if unchecked
    document.getElementById("viberTwo").checked = false
    console.log('unchecked');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="viberOne" onclick="onToggle()" type="checkbox" name="viberOne">
<input id="viberTwo" type="checkbox" name="viberTwo">
```